Bevel mask on texture rotation issue
I have this model that has scratched edges in Blender and when it's at no rotation, it is doing what it is supposed to. But when I rotate it 90 degrees to be standing up, the edge effect seems to rotate independently of the mesh (if that makes sense). How would I fix this?

Download .blend

If the object has no values of rotation, but still is rotated, it's probably because you applied the rotation when it was rotated 90 degrees. To counter this, you can just rotate it back 90 degrees then Ctrl+A > Apply Rotation.
If you're having rotation problems check the Transform Pivot Point you have selected. If it's rotating independently, you might have the Individual Origins pivot point selected. In that case, change the Transform Pivot Point to something that would fit your scenario, maybe Median Point.

Applying the rotation seems to fix it but if I rotate it anymore it goes back to changing texture, if I rotate it in edit mode it will resolve itself but once again if I rotate it again from there it goes back to changing itself. I tried adding a texture coordinate and mapping nodes to the mask but it doesn't seem to change anything.

there are other items related to the scene the problem is the metal thing.

I'm pretty sure its's just that you have a duplicated object. Rotate the metal thing, then delete the objects left behind.

They're all part of the same model, but the apply rotation will work now since the cards are the only things being moved. Thanks for the suggestion and further help.
